# NextJs – Mapping an array of links causes bugs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a site config which contains data for my menu links

```
//config.js

  menu: [
    {
      title: "Home",
      href: "/",
    },
    {
      title: "About",
      href: "/about/",
    },
  ]
```

Mapping this array into a component like the below causes some bugs in development mode.

```
//menu.jsx

  const renderMenuItems = (linkData) => {
    return map(linkData, (l) => {
      return (
        <Link key={l.href} as={l.href} href={l.href}>
          <a>{l.title}</a>
        </Link>
      );
    });
  };
```

I have noticed that refreshing while visiting one of the mapped locations causes the page to 404. Fonts are also not loaded. What is causing this?

Comment: can you show your router component?

Comment: @RedBaron pages and routing are automatically generated by NextJs using the  ["pages" folder structure](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)

Answer (score 0):

check this it might work

```
const renderMenuItems = linkData => {
  return (
    <>
      {linkData.map( l => {
        return (
          <Link key={l.href} as={l.href} href={l.href}>
            <a>{l.title}</a>
          </Link>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: if `linkData` is an array, you should use `linkData.map()`. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. I've given it a try. It doesn't resolve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, like [neil-morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11672616/neil-morgan) said, you should take a look at [array map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Then, I think your linkData props is probably undefined on initial component render.

Add this :

```
{linkData && linkData.map( l => {...})}
```

You can avoid this by init props whith `defaultProps`

```
renderMenuItems.defaultProps = {
     linkData : []
}
```

Moreover you can define propsTypes like following:

```
renderMenuItems.propTypes = {
   linkData : PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
       title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })),
```

Or alternatively with props interface if you're using TypeScript